# How to prevent pandas from rounding LDAP timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I am importing a CSV into a pandas dataframe. One column contains an 18 digit LDAP timestamp. I am trying to convert this timestamp however it appears that it is being rounded causing incorrect calculation.

data.csv:

```
Event ID,Clock-Time,ProcessID
10,133081599160584000,2824,44
10,133081599160584000,2824,84
10,133081599160667000,2824,44
10,133081599160667000,2824,92
10,133081599160667000,2824,116
10,133081599160667000,2824,132
```

script.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas
pandas.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
pandas.set_option('display.float_format','{:.0f}'.format)
pandas.set_option('display.precision', 20)

in_csv = "data.csv"

df = pandas.read_csv(in_csv,sep=',',header=0, float_precision='high')

print(df.dtypes)
print(df)

# convert win32 timestamp to unix timestamp
df['Clock-Time'] = df['Clock-Time'].apply(lambda timestamp: datetime(1601, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=(timestamp/10000000)))

print(df)
```

output:

```
Event ID        int64
Clock-Time    float64
ProcessID       int64
Size            int64
dtype: object
   Event ID         Clock-Time  ProcessID  Size
0        10 133082000000000000       2824    44
1        10 133082000000000000       2824    84
2        10 133082000000000000       2824    44
3        10 133082000000000000       2824    92
4        10 133082000000000000       2824   116
5        10 133082000000000000       2824   132
    Event ID          Clock-Time  ProcessID  Size
0        10 2022-09-21 02:13:20       2824    44
1        10 2022-09-21 02:13:20       2824    84
2        10 2022-09-21 02:13:20       2824    44
3        10 2022-09-21 02:13:20       2824    92
4        10 2022-09-21 02:13:20       2824   116
5        10 2022-09-21 02:13:20       2824   132
```

How can I get pandas to respect the full value so I can get the accurate timestamp?

Comment: `read_csv()` parse the `Clock-Time` column as `int64` on my system, not float. Do you have `NaN` in that column?

Comment: You might try passing `dtype={'col_b': np.int64)` to `read_csv`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the issue by creating your `.csv` from Windows Notepad.

```
   Event ID                 Clock-Time  ProcessID  Size
0        10 2022-09-20 15:05:16.058399       2824    44
1        10 2022-09-20 15:05:16.058399       2824    84
2        10 2022-09-20 15:05:16.066700       2824    44
3        10 2022-09-20 15:05:16.066700       2824    92
4        10 2022-09-20 15:05:16.066700       2824   116
5        10 2022-09-20 15:05:16.066700       2824   132
```

I bet you createad your `.csv` file from an Excel spreadsheet. By default, when you enter a number over 12 digits (e.g, a 18 digit LDAP timestamp) in a spreadsheet, the number is auto-corrected to scientific notation. For example, `"133081599160584000"` is converted to `"1.33082E+17"` (hence the single value `"133082000000000000"` in your initial dataframe after calling [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)). So when you export the spreadsheet to a text file (e.g, `.csv`), it is the scientific notation (what
Excel sees) that will be exported and not the actual `(x>12)-digit value`.

You can fix that upstream by changing the type of the concerned column in Excel
before creating the `.csv` :

[image]